# Получить fps сторонней игры

Tags: c#, графика

Нужно получить fps из, допустим, доты в реальном времени для того чтобы передать их в com-port. Устройство на другом конце порта будет это отображать.
Как получать фпс в реальном времени?

Comment: Щас навелосипедим :). Включаете показ fps в самой игре. Обычно он выводится где-нибудь в углу. Затем ваше приложение делает скриншот того угла экрана. И распознаёт изображение с помощью какой-нибудь библиотеки. Находит там число - вуаля!

Comment: я думал над этим, но оказалось слишком трудоёмким, да и счетчик фпс специально хочется убрать с экрана

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340347/monitoring-the-fps-of-a-direct-x-application

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понял, если игра Ваша, то:

```
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch frame = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
frame.Start();
//renderScene
frame.Stop();
double fps = 1000 / frame.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Comment: из какого окна будет браться fps? Из активного?

Comment: Это подсчет ФПС рендеринга перерисовки кадра. Что Вы хотели мне не понятно.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, он хотел для произвольной игры (которая, вероятно, рисуется через directx) получить fps из своего приложения на шарпе.

Comment: @Qwertiy это он написал только 11 минут назад

Comment: Главное, что написал ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy именно это я и имел ввиду

Comment: Написал и пропал без вести.

Answer (score 1):

Для мониторинга производительности DirectX в Windows существуют несколько провайдеров [Event Tracing for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ETW/event-tracing-portal). Наиболее интересны `Microsoft-Windows-D3D9` и `Microsoft-Windows-DXGI`, которые позволяют отследить событие рендеринга кадра. Простейший способ вычисления FPS заключается в том, чтобы посчитать количество событий рендеринга кадров ("PresentStart") в интервале времени и разделить на величину этого интервала.

Для того, чтобы задействовать ETW в C#, понадобится подключить пакет [Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent/).

Пример кода для отображения FPS всех запущенных процессов:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Session;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    //вспомогательный класс для хранения моментов времени отрисовки кадров
    public class TimestampCollection
    {
        const int MAXNUM = 1000;

        public string Name { get; set; }

        List<long> timestamps = new List<long>(MAXNUM + 1);
        object sync = new object();

        //добавление значения в коллекцию
        public void Add(long timestamp)
        {
            lock (sync)
            {
                timestamps.Add(timestamp);
                if (timestamps.Count > MAXNUM) timestamps.RemoveAt(0);
            }
        }

        //получение числа значений в определенном интервале времени
        public int QueryCount(long from, long to)
        {
            int c = 0;

            lock (sync)
            {
                foreach (var ts in timestamps)
                {
                    if (ts >= from && ts <= to) c++;
                }
            }
            return c;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        //коды событий (https://github.com/GameTechDev/PresentMon/blob/40ee99f437bc1061a27a2fc16a8993ee8ce4ebb5/PresentData/PresentMonTraceConsumer.cpp)
        public const int EventID_D3D9PresentStart = 1;
        public const int EventID_DxgiPresentStart = 42;

        //коды провайдеров ETW
        public static readonly Guid DXGI_provider = Guid.Parse("{CA11C036-0102-4A2D-A6AD-F03CFED5D3C9}");
        public static readonly Guid D3D9_provider = Guid.Parse("{783ACA0A-790E-4D7F-8451-AA850511C6B9}");

        static TraceEventSession m_EtwSession;
        static Dictionary<int, TimestampCollection> frames = new Dictionary<int, TimestampCollection>();       
        static Stopwatch watch = null;
        static object sync = new object();

        static void EtwThreadProc()
        {            
            //запускает отслеживание событий
            m_EtwSession.Source.Process();
        }

        static void OutputThreadProc()
        {
            //цикл вывода результатов в консоль
            while (true)
            {    
                long t1, t2;
                long dt = 2000;
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "." + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine();

                lock (sync)
                {
                    t2 = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                    t1 = t2 - dt;

                    foreach (var x in frames.Values)
                    {
                        Console.Write(x.Name + ": ");   

                        //получаем количество кадров в интервале времени
                        int count = x.QueryCount(t1, t2);

                        //вычисляем FPS
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} FPS", (double)count / dt * 1000.0);
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop tracing...");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] argv)
        {
            //создаем сессию ETW и регистрируем провайдеры
            m_EtwSession = new TraceEventSession("mysess");
            m_EtwSession.StopOnDispose = true;
            m_EtwSession.EnableProvider("Microsoft-Windows-D3D9");
            m_EtwSession.EnableProvider("Microsoft-Windows-DXGI");

            //подписываемся на событие
            m_EtwSession.Source.AllEvents += data =>
            {
                //интересуют только события рендеринга кадров
                if (((int)data.ID == EventID_D3D9PresentStart && data.ProviderGuid == D3D9_provider) ||
                ((int)data.ID == EventID_DxgiPresentStart && data.ProviderGuid == DXGI_provider))
                {
                    int pid = data.ProcessID;
                    long t;

                    lock (sync)
                    {
                        t = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds; 

                        //если найден новый процесс, добавляем в Dictionary
                        if (!frames.ContainsKey(pid))
                        {
                            frames[pid] = new TimestampCollection();

                            string name = "";
                            var proc = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
                            if (proc != null)
                            {
                                using (proc)
                                {
                                    name = proc.ProcessName;
                                }
                            }
                            else name = pid.ToString();

                            frames[pid].Name = name;
                        }

                        //добавляем кадр в коллекцию
                        frames[pid].Add(t);
                    }
                }
            };

            watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();            

            Thread thETW = new Thread(EtwThreadProc);
            thETW.IsBackground = true;
            thETW.Start();

            Thread thOutput = new Thread(OutputThreadProc);
            thOutput.IsBackground = true;
            thOutput.Start();

            Console.ReadKey();
            m_EtwSession.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Основан на коде проекта [PresentMon](https://github.com/GameTechDev/PresentMon)